# Il allait avoir le regret des sommets enneigés

Tags: temps-grammatical, imparfait, concordance-des-temps

*Paris-Briançon* de Philippe Besson :

> C'est du reste l'infatigable ambition de ce dernier (*) qui les avait
> conduits à quitter Briançon. Ayant décroché un très bon job à La
> Défense, et le salaire qui allait avec, il avait annoncé que c'était
> terminé, les Alpes, les sommets enneigés, la maison de pierre . Et la
> famille s'était retrouvée à Neuilly. Le garçon n'avait que sept ans.
> Pendant longtemps, le soir venu, en cherchant le sommeil, il
> **allait** avoir le regret des sommets enneigés, de la maison de pierre et, un jour, ça lui était passé.

(*) le père du garçon

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi *aller avoir le regret* est à l'imparfait ici. Quelle est la différence entre *allait avoir le regret* et *avait le regret*, *allait avoir le regret* et *irait avoir le regret* ? Je ne pense pas qu'il s'agisse de la [valeur modale de l'imparfait](https://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4198) ici.

Answer (score 3):

Cet usage est temporel, c'est un usage temporel du modal « aller » ; à l'imparfait « aller » peut indiquer le futur proche  dans le passé.

> ([Français Facile](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-104018.php))   Le futur proche dans le passé : aller (à l'imparfait)+ infinitif.

- Il allait avoir fini ses devoirs lorsque la radio annonça que les innondations avaient fait des dégats importants.

---

*addition en réponse à des commentaires*

1/ « Allait m’appeler le lendemain » et « m’appellerait le lendemain » sont équivalent.

2/

> **LBU Remarque R2 768**   Dans un récit au passé, les faits futurs sont ordinairement au conditionnel. Mais, si le récit est au présent historique, ils sont souvent au temps futur. Voir un ex. dans le § 769, R. Cf. § 887, b, 4°
>
> **LBU § 887 b) 4°** Dans les exposés historiques, on peut employer le futur simple
> pour énoncer un fait futur par rapport aux événements passés que l'on
> vient de raconter (notamment quand ceux-ci sont exprimés par le
> présent historique) :
> L'empereur pleure de la souffrance / D'avoir perdu ses preux [...]/
> et surtout
> de songer, lui, vainqueur des Espagnes / Qu'on FERA des chansons dans toutes ces
> montagnes (HUGO, Lég., X, 3). — Son œuvre AURA peu d'échos et il ne VENDRA
> qu'une seule toile de son vivant (Grand dict. enc. Lar., s. v. Van Gogh).

> https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-temps-et-les-valeurs-des-temps/
>
> • Le conditionnel peut avoir la valeur de futur quand il est en rapport avec un verbe conjugué à un temps du passé de l'indicatif (on peut l'appeler un futur du passé ou un futur dans le passé) :
> *Le fabriquant présentait les nouveautés que les commerçants vendraient.*

> http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=4138
> […] on emploie la valeur temporelle du conditionnel dans le style indirect libre. Le conditionnel figure alors dans une proposition indépendante, mais il est toujours lié à un verbe au passé, qui figure lui aussi dans une proposition indépendante. Encore une fois, si l'on remplaçait le verbe au passé par un verbe au présent, le verbe au conditionnel serait plutôt au futur.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - Georges ne pouvait s'empêcher de penser à Kim. Serait-elle de retour ce soir? (dans un contexte présent, on aurait : Georges ne peut s'empêcher de penser à Kim. Sera-t-elle de retour ce soir?)
> - Il sortit précipitamment. Il ne reviendrait pas de sitôt. (on pourrait aussi dire : Il savait qu'il ne reviendrait pas de sitôt.)

*On voit dans le second des exemples qui précèdent que le verbe en rapport avec lequel le conditionnel (ou le futur) est utilisé n'a pas à se trouver dans la même phrase.*

- Il avait échoué et il ne lui restait que des souvenirs. Pendant des années à venir il prendrait et reprendrait ce chemin perdu plutôt que la route principale, toujours en quête de ses souvenirs evanescents. (*user LPH*)

*On peut utiliser un présent narratif (aussi appelé « de narration »  ou encore « historique ») pour rendre la description  plus vivante. Mais dans ce cas il faut passer à un futur.*

- Il a échoué et il ne lui reste que des souvenirs. Pendant des années à venir il prendra et reprendra ce chemin perdu plutôt que la route principale, toujours en quête de ses souvenirs evanescents. (*user LPH*)

*Il n'y a rien qui empêche d'appliquer ces principes à la phrase de la question.*

- Et la famille s'était retrouvée à Neuilly. Le garçon n'avait que sept ans. Pendant longtemps, le soir venu, en cherchant le sommeil, il aurait le regret des sommets enneigés, de la maison de pierre et, un jour, ça lui était passé.
- Et la famille se retrouve à Neuilly. Le garçon n'a que sept ans. Pendant longtemps, le soir venu, en cherchant le sommeil, il aura le regret des sommets enneigés, de la maison de pierre et, un jour, ça lui passe.

3/ Pourquoi pas « irait avoir le regret » ? La raison est toute simple ; l'idée de futur proche dans le présent n'est associé qu'au temps du présent et celle de futur proche dans le passé n'est associée qu'à l'imparfait.

4/ Détail additionnel qui pourrait avoir de l'intérêt ; d'après user jlliagre le terme « futur proche » ne conviendrait pas. Il y a une distinction à faire, mais pour l'instant elle semble n'être faite que sous la nomenclature de « futur proche », la proximité étant une relation très relative, qui, à l'extrême, fait du futur proche un futur.

- Nous allons faire la conquète de la lune dans dix ans.
- Nous ferons la conquète de la lune dans dix ans.  (*même idée*)

> [Le Futur proche - Emploi](https://fr.syvum.com/cgi/online/serve.cgi/grammaire/verbe/futur_proche.html)
>
> **1. Avenir proche** Le futur proche s'emploie pour exprimer une action qui va se réaliser dans un avenir très proche.
> ♦  Il va pleuvoir bientôt.
> **2. Avenir lointain** Le futur proche s'emploie pour exprimer une action qui va se réaliser dans un avenir lointain.
> ♦  Nous allons déménager à Bordeaux dans deux ans.
> **3. Avertissement** Le futur proche s'emploie pour signaler un avertissement.
> ♦ Attention aux trottoirs glissants! vous allez tomber.

Comment: OK, merci. On dit [ici](https://www.gymglish.com/fr/frantastique-orthographe/grammaire-francaise/le-futur-proche-dans-le-passe) qu'on peut généralement remplacer le futur proche dans le passé par un conditionnel. _Victor avait dit qu’il **allait m’appeler** le lendemain. Victor avait dit qu’il **m’appellerait** le lendemain._ Est-ce que dans mon exemple, ce serait possible ? _il aurait  le regret des sommets enneigés_ ? Je pense que non. Puis, je ne comprends pas, pourquoi ne pas tout simplement dire _irait_, pourquoi employer l'imparfait dans ces cas-là.

Comment: @Oreste   Comme ce que l'on peut dire n'est pas simple j'ai rassemblé quelques références qui permettront de commencer à mieux comprendre, mais il n'y a pas moyen de les caser dans le champ des commentaires, alors je les copie dans le corps de ma réponse.

Comment: Merci beaucoup. _la proximité étant une relation très relative_ D'accord. _Le futur proche s'emploie pour exprimer une action qui va se réaliser dans un avenir lointain._ Mais pourquoi alors employer le futur proche et non le futur simple, pour exprimer l'idée de relativité ?

Comment: @Oreste Attention, on n'exprime pas l'idée de relativité, c'est une caractéristique intrinsèque du moyen d'expression du futur proche en utilisant le verbe « aller ». Ce qu'on exprime c'est un futur à plus ou moins brève échéance. Il est possible que l'utilisation de « aller » pour les futurs qui se réalisent dans un avenir assez lointain soit la conséquence du manque de définition d'une limite, du manque de perception par l'esprit des utilisateurs de la notion de proximité, tout ce qui serait resté en fait de notion attachée à cette modalité de « aller » étant la simple idée de futur.

Answer (score 1):

1. *Pourquoi "aller avoir le regret" est à l'imparfait ici ?*

   Le garçon avait sept ans. La phrase indique que par la suite (potentiellement durant plusieurs années), il lui est arrivé de multiples fois d'avoir des regrets avant de s'endormir, puis que ces épisodes avaient brutalement cessé. Il s'agit bien d'un futur dans le passé comme indiqué dans la réponse de LPH, mais pas ici un futur proche ou imminent à cause du *pendant longtemps*.
2. *Quelle est la différence entre allait **avoir le regret** et **avait le regret***.

   L'imparfait n'aurait plus situé ces endormissements dans le futur de ses sept ans mais comme des événement concurrents.
3. ***Irait avoir le regret*** :

   C'est une expression très curieuse. Elle est peut-être grammaticale mais n'est pas du tout idiomatique. Ici, *irait* préfixant *avoir* n'est plus un verbe semi-auxiliaire donc le petit garçon est censé se déplacer quelque part pour avoir un regret, ce qui n'a pas de sens puisqu'il est en train de chercher le sommeil dans son lit.
4. L'auteur aurait pu utiliser le passé simple mais comme avec l'imparfait, la chronologie aurait été moins claire :

   > Pendant longtemps, le soir venu, en cherchant le sommeil, il **eut** le regret des sommets enneigés, de la maison de pierre et, un jour, ça lui **passa**.

Comment: _Il s'agit bien d'un futur dans le passé... mais pas ici un futur proche ou imminent à cause du "pendant longtemps"_ Pourquoi alors employer le verbe _aller_ s'il ne s'agit pas d'un futur proche ? Il aurait été plus logique d'écrire _il aurait le regret_, non ?

Comment: Oui, je comprends ton objection. On doit pouvoir conserver la dénomination de futur proche mais la référence de ce futur qui n'est pas le présent de l'histoire (celui où il avait sept ans), mais un ensemble de soirées parmi toutes celles qui vont exister durant une période qui s'étale dans le temps (c'est à dire ici *pendant longtemps*). Il s'agit si on veut d'une succession de futurs proches.

Comment: D'accord. Mais il serait plus simple d'écrire _il aurait le regret_ au lieu de _allait avoir le regret_ ?

Comment: Ce ne serait pas forcément plus simple pour un francophone. En français, les temps composés sont souvent plus simples que les temps... simples ;-)

Comment: Mais _il aurait le regret_ est correct, tout de même, non ? Oui, il devrait l'être. Quelle est la différence entre _il aurait le regret_ et _allait avoir le regret_, est-ce que ce dernier décrit une continuité ?

Comment: J'ai du mal avec la phrase : *Pendant longtemps, le soir venu, en cherchant le sommeil, il **aurait** le regret des sommets enneigés, de la maison de pierre et, un jour, ça lui **était** passé.* J'ai la sensation qu'il y a un problème de concordance des temps et qu'il faudrait dire *et, un jour, ça lui serait passé* mais dans ce dernier cas, on introduit une incertitude qui est absente du texte original.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135642/discussion-between-oreste-and-jlliagre).